# Why does calling a function with new not return same reference when calling without new

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, you can create a reference to functions two ways:

```
 var f1 = function myFunction1()
 {
 };

 var f2 = new function myFunction2()
 {
   var x = 1;
 };
```

f1 returns a reference to a function but f2 doesn't. What exactly does f2 return? The following is written on Mozilla's website:

> Invoking the Function constructor as a function (without using the new
>   operator) has the same effect as invoking it as a constructor.

So if it's the "same effect", why do they return two different things?

[Functions and function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, and the `Function` constructor has an uppercase `F`, your code examples don't seem to be related to the question you're asking, but the second example would return a new instance of the `myFunction2` function, i.e. an object, which isn't generally something you see used like that very often (or ever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `Function` constructor**

By *constructor* they mean the reserved keyword [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

```
Function()
```

and

```
new Function()
```

are indeed equivalent as both return a reference to an annonyomous function.

**The `function` operator**

As adeneo and you have noted, your examples employ the `function` *operator* (with a lowercase `l`) which is used for function declaration.

Comment: Missed the uppercase on the word Function. Makes a difference.